# OS X [Yosemite] : cannot run rails app using nginx + unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn, osx-yosemite

I am trying to test a very basic Rails app (called simpleapp)  in this environment, ( Nginx is installed and running fine for html/php web sites) , Unicorn is starting but nothing happen upon application request.

I am using 'dnmasq' and a resolver for .dev domains on my localhost

DNMASQ & RESOLVER

```
#  my brew --prefix)/etc/dnsmasq.conf is :
address=/.dev/127.0.0.1

# my /etc/resolved/dev is :  
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

NGINX

```
   # my /user/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf is :

    worker_processes  1;

    error_log  /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/error.log debug;

    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }

    http {
        include             mime.types;
        default_type        application/octet-stream;

        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

        access_log  /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/access.log  main;
        sendfile            on;
        keepalive_timeout   65;
        index index.html index.php;
        include /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*; 
    }
```

and I have in /user/local/etc/nginx/sites-available ( ln to sites-enabled) a proxy to port 3001

```
   # /user/local/etc/nginx/sites-available/simpleapp :
        server {
      listen       80;
      server_name  simpleapp.dev;
      client_max_body_size 4G;
      keepalive_timeout 5;

      root  /Users/myself/Developpement/RAILS-41/simpleapp;

      location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass_header X-Accel-Redirect;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
          proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:3001;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
```

UNICORN

I am using 'foreman' to start my unicorn app server

```
# in my simple/Procfile I got :
web: bundle exec unicorn -p 3001 -c ./config/unicorn.conf.rb
```

and

```
#my config/unicorn.conf.rb is as simple as :
listen 3001
worker_processes 2
pid "./tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "./log/unicorn-error.log"
stdout_path "./log/unicorn.log"a
```

I reload my nginx and start foreman :

```
sudo nginx -s relaod
foreman start
19:13:30 web.1  | started with pid 16860
```

UNICORN LOG

```
    I, [2014-10-30T19:15:56.961299 #17023]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:3001 fd=9
    I, [2014-10-30T19:15:56.961785 #17023]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
    I, [2014-10-30T19:15:56.963273 #17023]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
    I, [2014-10-30T19:15:56.964391 #17023]  INFO -- : master process ready
    I, [2014-10-30T19:15:56.965524 #17119]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=17119
    I, [2014-10-30T19:15:56.966147 #17119]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
    I, [2014-10-30T19:15:56.966512 #17120]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawned pid=17120
    I, [2014-10-30T19:15:56.967227 #17120]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
    I, [2014-10-30T19:16:09.746993 #17119]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
    I, [2014-10-30T19:16:09.746993 #17120]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
```

in my browser I try to reach the simple rails app :

```
   http://simpleapp.dev
```

but nothing happen, and no log information....

where am I wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

solved it , adding an upstream block into  nginx.conf

```
....
include /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*; 

upstream upstream_server {
    server localhost:3001;
}
```

and modifying the simple server description :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  simpleapp.dev;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://upstream_server;
    }
}
```

so I can have multiple rails app ( defining multiple upstreams block...